# How to restore a Windows Easy Transfer file from a 64bit machine to a 32bit machine?

Tags: windows-7, migration

Using a 32bit laptop, I saved my settings etc. using "Windows Easy Transfer" from the Win7 RC.

I set the file destination to a Win2K R2 machine that happened to be 64bit.

When I re-installed my laptop and tried to restore my settings from the file I'd saved I was surprised to get an error: "Windows Easy Transfer can't transfer files from a 64-bit computer to a 32-bit computer."

Is there a known workaround? Ideas on how to unpack the file and get my stuff?

Comment: Is the laptop 64-bit capable?

Comment: Nope.. it's the same laptop I made the .mig file from - why having saved it to a 64-bit machine makes it unusable is unfathomable

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is a really old question, but I do not like unanswered ones ;)*

There is a tool for extracting files from `.mig` archives called Mike Morawski’s MigViewer Utility.

You can find download links and usage information [here](http://www.migee.com/2011/01/17/mig-recover-and-viewer-utility-alpha/) and [here](http://www.migee.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/MigViewer0.5.zip) is the direct download link.